# Rackmounting a tower chassis HP BLc3000 Blade System

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, rackmount, bladecenter, blade-chassis

Ok, so we have a HP BLc3000 that we are bringing in from a remote office to our central datacentre, its currently in its purchased tower / pedestal configuration (with the wheels and all that)

Is it possible to rackmount (Looks like there are 2 plastic sections that pops off and the wheels unbolt), I have found the rackmount rails on partsurfer, but obviously this is all good in theory, is it that simple or is it not as straightforward as that

Comment: I bet you wish it was a Dell VRTX ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the [official word from HP today is "**not possible**"](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/blades/components/enclosures/c-class/c3000/questionsanswers.html#a4). It also seems that the enclosure dimensions are different between the rack and tower setups.

Please refer to the [C3000 maintenance guide](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c01126895/c01126895.pdf). There are [several resellers](http://www.serverworlds.com) who would probably be willing to sell you a rackmount CTO chassis at discount. Also recall that C7000 enclosures can be found cheap ($1k-$3k).

There are common components from the chassis perspective, and I suspect that (minus the bezel differences) it's technically possible to fit the rails to the enclosure. The tower wasn't popular (it's now discontinued), and I don't have one to check right now.

[image]

Comment: There are common components from the chassis perspective, and I suspect that (minus the bezel differences) it's technically possible to fit the rails to the enclosure. The tower wasn't popular (it's now discontinued), and I don't have one to check right now. [ASR5K-00-P24-K9-RF](https://gracileit.com/asr5k-00-p24-k9-rf-reman-asr-5000-platform-starter-bdl)